# How to find exact location (not by ip address) Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, location, geocode, rails-geocoder

So I tried geocode but it can only find the users location based on ip addresses but I need the exact lat and long values of the user. Btw what is the accuracy of the ip address method.

Answer (score 2):

Ask the user on the client side for Geolocation permissions. You'll get the coordinates directly and you don't have to geocode anything. If the user doesn't give you the permission you shouldn't trying to locate them anyway.

**Simple JS example:**

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    // Do something with the coordinates

    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
```

More information [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp).

Comment: Note that in Chrome, this requires a secure domain (SSL). Currently, Firefox does not. Haven't tested on others.

Comment: @CarlMarkham Good point! It's negligent to transfer such sensitive data over an unencrypted connection anyway in my opinion.

Comment: firefox also asking for ssl now

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Google GeoCode API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) but after 2000 requests, you would need to pay for it. This works on the idea that you have the users address or even just a post code (Zip code).

In terms of detecting location from IP, pretty hard if not impossible. You can usually get a broad location (City, County or State) but not the actual house or street etc.

Comment: It depends if the request comes from a static company or dynamic IP. But you can not say if the request is just routed through a gateway with this IP and the user is at a very different place actually. So you are mostly right.

Comment: @Tobias Yeh, I had a feeling I would get some of it wrong. The main point is that you cannot accurately pin point a location via IP address.